# Why aren't there cryptocoin wallet extensions for Firefox? (2015)

Tags: firefox-addon, bitcoin, dogecoin-api

I was looking around on Chrome extension stores and I saw some pretty cool extensions like the Dogecoin Browser wallet, KryptoKit and Blockchain extensions. Why aren't there any for Firefox?

There seems like there's a good reason out there because there are exactly 0 extensions like that for Firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can definitely make one, if you want help let me know. :) Thanks for browsing the gallery and noticing then sharing this info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that Firefox extensions are more of a pain to build.  And in addition to slightly higher development complexity, they took a while to get their act together on deciding exactly what extensions would and wouldn't have to do / be allowed to do.  We at KryptoKit have talked about doing a Firefox extension, but until we see specific user demand for it our open source recommendation is just to run our Chrome extension on Chromium.

Comment: I can help you out. Join the other devs on IRC channels you'll find people that can hook you up with templates to get you started very easily. I actually can help you out a lot. Get on at irc://moznet/introduction and irc://moznet/extdev we'll get an addon out really fast and easy to maintain. The reason it seems daunting to start is there is so much you can do with ff addons but the documentation doesnt detail it all for new comers. I say make at least a lite version and see how much traffic you get, then you can go for full blown. I think you'll be happy when you get it out.

Comment: We'll definitely consider it.  I'm a big fan of Mozilla myself, and if we could deploy to both with minimal effort it would definitely be nice to have both.

Comment: Let me know if you need help I'm here for ya.